# Codeforces judge gives error even though code runs fine

Tags: python, python-3.7

Hi guys I'm absolutely new to python

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/4/A

> Print YES, if the input weight can be divided into two parts, each of them weighing even number of kilos; and NO in the opposite case.

I was solving this problem on Codeforces.
My code is:

```
n = int(input("Enter the weight: "))

a = round((n/2))

b = n-a

if(((a%2)!=0) and ((b%2)!=0)):
    print("NO")
else:
    print("YES")
```

Codeforces says my answer is wrong on test 1......
What actually am I doing wrong? TIA

Comment: @JohnnyMopp brother tried or, still shows error. Tried Int() instead of round(), still shows error. What do you suggest the code should be like exactly?

Comment: If I understand the problem, the solution is "YES" only if `n` is even, else "NO" since even + even = even. That is, there is no way to add 2 even numbers together and get an odd result.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number. You need to divide it into two parts. Such that each part is even.  We can never get two even numbers from an odd number. So, whenever the input is odd number answer will be "No". But can we get two even numbers from 2?
No! For an even number greater than 2, the answer will be "Yes".